# Show both the same columns with other type

Tags: sql-server, join

I have this:

```
use [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT V.No_, VPL.[Location Code],V.Name, 
       SUM(VPL.Amount)  AS Total, 
       V.[Freight-free Limit]
     -- ISNULL(CAST( V.[Freight-free Limit] AS VARCHAR(10)), 'geen waarde')  
 FROM [Verploegen POC$Purch_ Inv_ Line] VPL
  JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
     ON VPL.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = V.No_
--WHERE [Buy-from Vendor No_] =  '3929' -- is empty??' --'3932' --'3929' --'3923' --'3904' --'3885' --'3820' --'3894' 
WHERE VPL.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = '3929' 
      AND VPL.Type = 1  AND ([Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') 
GROUP BY VPL.[Location Code], V.[Freight-free Limit], V.No_, V.Name  --, VPL.[Direct Unit Cost]
ORDER BY V.Name
```

And there is a propertie:VPL.Type = 1, but you have the same propertie with `type=2`. But in the results I want to show both properties so with type =1 and with `type =2`. Because the Total of `type = 1` is different then the Total of `type = 2.` The result with `type = 1` is like this:

```
3929    AM  ASF Fischer BV  20.89000000000000000000 350.00000000000000000000
3929    DB  ASF Fischer BV  -0.29000000000000000000 350.00000000000000000000
3929    DL  ASF Fischer BV  0.34000000000000000000  350.00000000000000000000
3929    RD  ASF Fischer BV  20.06000000000000000000 350.00000000000000000000
3929    ZM  ASF Fischer BV  0.04000000000000000000  350.00000000000000000000
```

So How to make an extra column with type = 2?

Thank you

If I do this:

```
use [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT V.No_, VPL.[Location Code],V.Name, 
       SUM(VPL.Amount)  AS Total, 
       SUM(VPL.Amount) as total2,
       V.[Freight-free Limit]
     -- ISNULL(CAST( V.[Freight-free Limit] AS VARCHAR(10)), 'geen waarde')  
 FROM [Verploegen POC$Purch_ Inv_ Line] VPL 
  JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
     ON VPL.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = V.No_
--WHERE [Buy-from Vendor No_] =  '3929' -- is empty??' --'3932' --'3929' --'3923' --'3904' --'3885' --'3820' --'3894' 
WHERE VPL.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = '3929' 
      AND VPL.Type = 1  AND ([Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') 
GROUP BY VPL.[Location Code], V.[Freight-free Limit], V.No_, V.Name  --, VPL.[Direct Unit Cost]
ORDER BY V.Name
```

as result this:

```
3929    AM  ASF Fischer BV  20.89000000000000000000 20.89000000000000000000 350.00000000000000000000
3929    DB  ASF Fischer BV  -0.29000000000000000000 -0.29000000000000000000 350.00000000000000000000
3929    DL  ASF Fischer BV  0.34000000000000000000  0.34000000000000000000  350.00000000000000000000
3929    RD  ASF Fischer BV  20.06000000000000000000 20.06000000000000000000 350.00000000000000000000
3929    ZM  ASF Fischer BV  0.04000000000000000000  0.04000000000000000000  350.00000000000000000000
```

But Total and Total2 have now the same values

You  mean like this?

```
use [VERPLOEGEN-NAV2009-LIVE]
SELECT V.No_, VPL.[Location Code],V.Name,

       sum(case when Type =1 then 1 else 0 end )As type1sum,
        sum(case when Type =2 then 1 else 0 end )As type2sum,
       V.[Freight-free Limit]
     -- ISNULL(CAST( V.[Freight-free Limit] AS VARCHAR(10)), 'geen waarde')  
 FROM [Verploegen POC$Purch_ Inv_ Line] VPL 
  JOIN [Verploegen POC$Vendor] V
     ON VPL.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = V.No_
--WHERE [Buy-from Vendor No_] =  '3929' -- is empty??' --'3932' --'3929' --'3923' --'3904' --'3885' --'3820' --'3894' 
WHERE VPL.[Buy-from Vendor No_] = '3929' 
      AND  ([Posting Date] BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31') 
GROUP BY VPL.[Location Code], V.[Freight-free Limit], V.No_, V.Name  --, VPL.[Direct Unit Cost]
ORDER BY V.Name
```

output:

```
3929    AM  ASF Fischer BV  4   39  350.00000000000000000000
3929    DB  ASF Fischer BV  4   67  350.00000000000000000000
3929    DL  ASF Fischer BV  8   128 350.00000000000000000000
3929    RD  ASF Fischer BV  4   36  350.00000000000000000000
3929    ZM  ASF Fischer BV  1   10  350.00000000000000000000
```

But where I have to put the sum(amount) then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Vpl.type from where and use SUM with CASE..

```
select 
 col1..
,sum(case when Type =1 then amount else 0 end )As type1sum,
 sum(case when Type =2 then amount else 0 end )As type2sum
from
table
grouping columns
```

Comment: @SavantCode: i have updated,this will give you two sums based on vpltype value

Comment: HI, I also posted this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038090/select-case-with-a-pivot. Maybe you have a ideer of it

Comment: @SavantCode:Please check this article,it may take 5 minutes,but if you post even basic questions,you will get amazing responses...spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Oke, but can you maybe look at it? And the link you have give me doesnt exist anymore

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/   @SavantCode,see this

Comment: Oke, I have improved my question. But do you have maybe an asware on my post? Thank you

Comment: Oke,but do you have an suggestion?